# Как вызвать метод в классе? django python

Tags: python, django

Создаю форму в django, но надо чтобы форма выбиралась в соответствии с переданным tag в ulr

```
class OrderAddView(CreateView):
    tag_url_kwarg = 'tag'
    from_class = get_order_form(tag_url_kwarg)
    template_name = 'orders/order_add.html'    

    def get_order_form(self,tag):
        print('tag', tag)
        if tag == 'fast':
            return FastOrdersForm
        if tag == 'simple':
            return SimpleOrdersForm
```

Как лучше реализовать? как вызывать метод в классе?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55957490/12884300

Comment: спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать что-то вроде маппера форм, где ключами будут слаги, а значениями - формы. Например,

```
FORMS_MAPPER = {
  'fast': FastOrdersForm,
  'simple': SimpleOrdersForm
}
```

а затем в контроллере используя метод [**`get_form_class`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_class), получить соответствующую форму:

```
class OrderAddView(CreateView):
    tag_url_kwarg = 'tag'
    template_name = 'orders/order_add.html'  

    def get_form_class(self):
        return FORMS_MAPPER[self.kwargs.get('tag', 'fast')]
```

Более подробный ответ можете посмотреть здесь - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55957261/django-formview-with-dynamic-forms/55957490#55957490